# How to prevent Meteor app with crosswalk package crashing during compilation for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

So I'm trying to add crosswalk to my Meteor project and I'm getting this compile error. I know its crosswalk causing it because if I remove crosswalk it will go away.

```
While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /Users/EXAMPLE/Documents/example/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --device
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.


   /Users/EXAMPLE/Documents/example/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
   throw e;
   ^
   ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk
   to device:     pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-debug.apk
   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

ExitWithCode:1
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to full uninstall the application from your device first. Settings->Applications->Application Manager->YOUR APP->Clear Data. Then Uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios you will need to run

```
adb uninstall com.package.name
```

Uninstalling form the Application Manager for some reason doesn't always remove all the files.